# Varchar to Datetime conversion - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How can I convert a varchar column into a datetime field. The varchar field has the date and time in the below format

```
t_time
-------
20140314163955
```

The below doesn't work

```
CAST(t_time AS datetime)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need the time part as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, in order to keep it clean would be to use a function, like the one below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CONVERT_DATETIME_STRING_TO_DATE (@StringDate NVARCHAR(14))
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RESULT DATETIME

SELECT @RESULT = CONVERT(datetime, substring(@StringDate, 0, 9))
SELECT @RESULT = DATEADD(HOUR, CAST(SUBSTRING(@StringDate, 9, 2) AS INT), @RESULT)
SELECT @RESULT = DATEADD(MINUTE, CAST(SUBSTRING(@StringDate, 11, 2) AS INT), @RESULT)
SELECT @RESULT = DATEADD(SECOND, CAST(SUBSTRING(@StringDate, 13, 2) AS INT), @RESULT)

RETURN (@RESULT)
END
```

The conversion could be done in one `SELECT` statement, but I think it's better to separate each step of adding hours, minutes, seconds so it's clearer code and easier to maintain.

Then, just call the function from your table, like:

```
SELECT CONVERT_DATETIME_STRING_TO_DATE(t_time)
FROM myTable
```

**Update:**

If you have access only to do `SELECT` statements, then use something like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, CAST(SUBSTRING(t_time, 13, 2) AS INT), DATEADD(MINUTE, CAST(SUBSTRING(t_time, 11, 2) AS INT), DATEADD(HOUR, CAST(SUBSTRING(t_time, 9, 2) AS INT), CONVERT(DATETIME, substring(t_time, 0, 9)))))
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: The application I am using runs a select to retrieve the rows from the table. Since the date is in the format I mentioned above. The application required a one liner to convert the varchar to a timestamp for it to process the row.

Comment: @PottaPitot So? You can still use this function in a regular `SELECT` statement, like I've shown in my example on how you can call the function after you created it.

Comment: The problem is I cannot create a function. All I have at my disposal is a select access privilege that reads from an existing table only and one of these columns contain the timestamp presented in the above format

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
DECLARE @s AS VARCHAR(14)
DECLARE @dt AS DATETIME

SET @s = '20140314163955'
SET @dt = CAST(SUBSTRING(@s, 1,8) as datetime)

SELECT DATEADD(Second, 
               CAST(Substring(@s, 13,2) AS INT) ,
               DATEADD(minute,
                       CAST(Substring(@s, 11,2) AS INT) ,
                       DATEADD(hour, 
                               CAST(Substring(@s, 9,2) AS INT), 
                               @dt))) AS [DateTime]
```

Comment: The application I am using runs a select to retrieve the rows from the table. Since the date is in the format I mentioned above. The application required a one liner to convert the varchar to a timestamp for it to process the row.